# How can I use regex to fix a string like "--------ab-c" to just "ab-c"?

Tags: regex

I plan to use regex to filter URL like

`--------------r5---sn-gpt7dm7l.googlevideo.com` 
to

`r5---sn-gpb7dm7l.googlevideo.com`

Comment: Please take a look at the [SO Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). These two documents will help others answer your question quicker. And increase the chances of your question not being removed from the site.

Comment: I can't reduce more. I can't imagine how could be better. I know that there are tons of questions about regex, I see many of them, but no one resolve. It's not fair consider this as a bad question.

Comment: Don't reduce the question add more. Like some code you have tried and other things of that nature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like `-{4,}`?

> `a{3,}` Matches at least 3 consecutive `a` characters.

Example:  https://regex101.com/r/LmRMB2/1/

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not work bcz the quantity of "-" could be variable. Some URLs could have 1,2,3 and others could have 100 "-" characters.

Comment: Can you please provide me a better information about how urls are formatted? They just have 1 or 2 or 100 `-` characters before the url you want to get? And there's also a random number of `-` inside the url you want to get? They always have `r5---sn-gpt7dm7l.googlevideo.com` in it? What are the constant parts?

Comment: Nice to know! Have a great day